# How to make Mac OS use the python installed by Homebrew

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I have searched online for a while for this question, and what I have done so far is

1. installed python32 in homebrew
2. changed my .bash_profile and added the following line to it:

> export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH

but when I close the terminal and start again, I type 'which python', it still prints:

> /usr/bin/python

and type 'python --version' still got:

> Python 2.7.2

I also tried the following instruction:

> brew link --overwrite python

or try to remove python installed by homebrew by running this instruction:

> brew remove python

but both of the above two instructions lead to this error:

> Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/python

can anybody help, thanks

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`brew install python` or `brew info python` output mentions:

> Unversioned symlinks `python`, `python-config`, `pip` etc. pointing to
> `python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3` etc., respectively, have been installed into
> /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin

So running

```sh
% echo 'export PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/libexec/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.zprofile
% source ~/.zprofile
# For bash use ~/.bash_profile.
```

gets you those symlinks created by Homebrew - python=python3, pip=pip3 etc

```sh
% python --version
Python 3.9.10
% pip --version
pip 21.3.1 from /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was trying for this for an hour.

Comment: Heads up to folks that you shouldn't just put this into your path blindly, for example, the directory suggested in this answer does not exist for me. On my system, Python version number is part of the path directory and I had a couple of versions of python installed via homebrew so I needed to choose one to represent python3 in bash profile.

Comment: @adamlogan I have updated answer to include `brew info python` which gets you current path to add

Comment: Note that currently, the brew will install 3.10, so use: `echo 'export PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.10/libexec/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.zprofile`

Comment: I thought brew was meant to manage this for us. Like put symlinks in our existing path instead of in some random folder we have to manually add to our path and change if we need to swap versions at all.

Answer (score 38):

If you want to install Python 3 using Homebrew:

```
$ brew install python3
==> Downloading http://python.org/ftp/python/3.3.0/Python-3.3.0.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/python3-3.3.0.tar.bz2
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.0 --enable-ipv6 --datarootdir=/usr/local/Cell
==> make
==> make install PYTHONAPPSDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.0
==> make frameworkinstallextras PYTHONAPPSDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.0/share/python3
==> Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.35.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/distribute-0.6.35.tar.gz
==> /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.0/bin/python3.3 -s setup.py install --force --verbose --install-li
==> Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-1.3.1.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/pip-1.3.1.tar.gz
==> /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.0/bin/python3.3 -s setup.py install --force --verbose --install-li
==> Caveats
Homebrew's Python3 framework
  /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.0/Frameworks/Python.framework

Distribute and Pip have been installed. To update them
  pip3 install --upgrade distribute
  pip3 install --upgrade pip

To symlink "Idle 3" and the "Python Launcher 3" to ~/Applications
  `brew linkapps`

You can install Python packages with
  `pip3 install <your_favorite_package>`

They will install into the site-package directory
 /usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages
Executable python scripts will be put in:
 /usr/local/share/python3
so you may want to put "/usr/local/share/python3" in your PATH, too.

See: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python
```

Once installed update your system `PATH` variable, add the next line to `~/.bash_profile`

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH
```

And then:

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

Now launch Python:

```
$ python3
Python 3.3.0 (default, Mar 26 2013, 10:01:40) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.27)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

You can check python3 path:

```
$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Comment: If you are installing python 3 from Homebrew, then the bin is called `python3`

Comment: If you are installing python 3 using homebrew (using `brew install python3`), then to run python you should invoke `python3` from terminal in other case you will be running python 2.

Comment: when I type 'python3' in the terminal, I got '-bash: python3: command not found'

Comment: Are you sure that homebrew has installed python successfully? Are you sure that you are not confusing python2 with python3? check steps again. Check if `/usr/local/bin/python3` exists

Comment: thanks very much, it seems that I use to install python32 instead of python, I used your instruction, it works.

Comment: one more question. if I type 'which python' in terminal, I still got '/usr/bin/python', and I tried to add an alias in .bash_profile as the way aga_pan provided, and type 'python --version', it prints 'Python 3.3.2'. Is this behavior correct?

Comment: IMHO using alias here might be confusing as long as python normally refers to version 2, I can't tell if it is a normal behavior, you should ask another question (maybe in superuser.com)

Comment: If you dont want to call it python3 and instead keep it simple as python
run these  `brew unlink python@2 && brew link python@3`. then add this to your bash profile `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: if you prefer to use the `python` command instead of the `python3` command, just add the following symbolic link: `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python`. You might have to update the version number in the command to match whatever Homebrew installed.

Comment: This answer is outdated, as of 2023 and MacOS13 it's plain incorrect.

Answer (score 16):

You may try adding this line to your .bash_profile

```
alias python=python3
```

Comment: Just tried, if I type 'which python', I got '/usr/bin/python', and 'python --version' got '-bash: python3: command not found'

Comment: @photosynthesis I just used this method to make 'python' to invoke 'python2.6'. It should work the same way as python3

Comment: Single quotes are not necessary, works without them. Edited the answer 

Answer (score 7):

I came through the same issue and did some research. I found that someone has created a bug for the same issue under the [azure/cli](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli) repository. You can find that issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/5982). I am providing the same solution here which was very easy and fixed my issue:

Most probably the Brew is broken and needs some patching or fixing. So run `brew doctor` command which will give you a summary about what is happening.
Below is what I got:

```
mymac:bin sidmishra$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: The following directories do not exist:
/usr/local/sbin

You should create these directories and change their ownership to your account.
  sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/sbin
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/sbin

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
  /usr/local/lib/LibSideSyncOSX9.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/ss_conn_lib.dylib

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
  python
```

The awesome stuff about the command `brew doctor` is that it not only tells you issues but also suggests you the solution steps in most of the cases. 
So, I ran all the commands suggested by the brew and to link I ran the following command:

```
brew link python
```

Above command threw me an error:

```
mymac$ brew link python
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1... Error: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework
```

It seems that `/urs/local/Frameworks` doesn't have enough rights for my current user. So, I ran the following command and gave enough rights to my current user:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Frameworks/
```

After running above command I ran linking command again, and it worked!!!

```
mymac$ brew link python
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1... 1 symlinks created
```

Now run following command to get the current selected python version:

```
python --version
```

Above command should give you `3.7.1` (as of 21st Dec 2018) or new version for the python. There might be a chance that your Mac would have `python2` set by default. If the version is not `python3` then you have to a couple of steps to use the latest `python3` over `python2` version. Here are the steps:

**Using Shell:**

- Open `~/.bash_login`or `~/.bash_profile`or `~/.cshrc`or `~/.profile`or `~/.tcshrc`or `~/.zprofile`, whatever shell you are using for commands, in edit mode. You may have to use `sudo` to edit them.
- Add following steps to it:

  PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin:${PATH}"
  export PATH
- Also, add following for backup:

  alias python=python3

OR
**Using homebrew:**

Run following commands to unlink python2 and link python3:

```
mymac$ brew unlink python@2
mymac$ brew link python@3
```

Above will unlink python2 and link python3.

Hope some of you will get helped from this answer.

Good Day!!!

Comment: TL;DR: `brew unlink python@2 && brew link python@3` helped me. Other text won't read. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From `$ brew info python`:

> This formula installs a python2 executable to /usr/local/bin.
>   If you wish to have this formula's python executable in your PATH then add
>   the following to ~/.bash_profile:
>     export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"

Then confirm your python executable corresponds to the correct installation:

`$ which python` or

`$ python --version`

Answer (score 0):

Installing with Homebrew is recommended on macOS. That being said, Python 2.7 comes with Mac OS; however, it is deprecated and will be removed soon. As such, you should be using Python3 and newer.

1. Install Homebrew.

```sh
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

2. Run `brew install python`

Once Python is installed, Homebrew will say that the installation is complete, but that you already have Python 2.7 installed. This is nice, but we want to set it to actually see python3 as an option

2. Use `brew link`
3. Confirm by running `which python3`, the path should be `/usr/local/bin/python3`