# Homebrew: Packages are installed for wrong python version (mac)

Tags: python, python-3.x, homebrew

Homebrew is installing the package I need for python 2.7, which is the default version that comes with Mac, but I need it to be installed for python 3.4. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try `pip3 install` versus just `pip install`.

Look at the versions:

```
pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

pip3 --version                                                             
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Listing the executable for python 3.4 before python 2.7 in your PATH might help if you haven't tried it already. Otherwise maybe something here might help? [How to make Mac OS use the python installed by Homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419500/how-to-make-mac-os-use-the-python-installed-by-hombrew)

Comment: I don't even have python2.7 in my path, this is my PATH: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin

Comment: I noticed this when running brew config from terminal:                     Python: /usr/local/bin/python => /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7

Comment: Hmm, strange that it isn't seeing python 3 since it seems to be first in your path. It does seem like homebrew's python is pointing at python two though. What does running 'which python' give you?

Comment: /usr/bin/python

Comment: In any case you might try using brew switch if you have both pythons installed with homebrew

Comment: Then it's definitely using Mac's python, like you said. I would try a brew switch and export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

Comment: How would I do that? I didn't install python3.4 through brew, I already had 2.7 and 3.4 installed before ever introducing homebrew

Comment: Then all I know to do is to make sure the 3.4 executable is where you expect it to be. From your PATH, it seems like you expect it in "/Libra‌ry/Frameworks/Python‌​.framework/Versions/‌​3.4/bin", so I would make sure the python executable exists in that directory. If it isn't there, you'll need to find where it installed to and add that place to your PATH. Otherwise I'm really not sure why your machine is using the python in /usr/bin :/