# Brew Installing Python3 on El Capitan

Tags: python-3.x, homebrew, osx-elcapitan

I need to install Python3, Pip, and PySerial. I attempted to follow [this Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419500/how-to-make-mac-os-use-the-python-installed-by-homebrew) on installing Python3 via Homebrew. However, when I manually go in and check, Python3 is in:

> usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula

I am assuming this isn't the proper location? At this point should I install python3 via Homebrew and start over?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out. A combination of reinstalling python3, and removing unbrewed header files via *brew doctor* fixed the issue.